# Using SUB with values higher than 128 in an 8 bit system

Tags: avr, assembly

how does the SUB instruction work in AVR assembly? does it take the twos compliment and add it or does it function differently? If I subtract two 8- bit numbers, say 1 - 2 and the answer is -1, should I expect the twos complement of 1 or some other value?
I'm not sure how to think about the question when thinking about numbers higher than 128, my understanding of twos compliment is that you half the magnitude of numbers you can count to, but if I give the SUB instruction to do:

2 - 255

what do the bit operations look like? My understanding is that the twos compliment of 255 requires nine bits (100000001), does it just overflow in an 8 bit system? Would the math look like:

00000010 + 00000001 = 00000011

Comment: You are correct that you can’t represent +255 in 8bits. You’d need 16bits or more - the AVR does math operations in chunks of 8 bits, so that determines your bit widths. To do a 16 bit add/subtract use two instructions. Note the carry/borrow flag - it is important.

Comment: @Justme [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf) is the most detailed document i could find

Comment: @Justme  The issue is probably less clear for a newcomer than you may expect. The SBC command is on page 147 [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf) -> It would be useful if you could explain it to Tzanker.

Comment: Anyone downvotong or close-voting this may wish to have a look at page 147 in the [AVR instruction set manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf). Presumably you are AVR competent to make this decision  - so, adding a brief comment or a short answer would help.

Comment: This issue is not really AVR specific. You can use any decent assembly tutorial to learn the basics, and then map your new knowledge to the AVR's code. In a second step use your device or simulator to do some experiments.

Comment: @thebusybee  The issue MAY NOT be AVR specific. If you look at the AVR instruction set manual the answer is not simple.  Maybe you could add some specific guidance in this case. Note that the AVR SUB instruction includes 2's complement flags.

Comment: I believe (by all means someone correct me) that the AVR SBC instruction is NOT 2's complement BUT that it sets flags which allow 2's complement results to be produced. 
eg in base 10, 9 - 10 = -1. In an unsigned 8 bit system 1001 - 1010 will produce$FF = 11111111 = -127 in 2's complement. By use of the provided flags this can be adjusted if 2's complement results are wanted.